# Lightning Example for Multi-step wizard in Modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, quickaction

I am currently building a (set of) Lightning components for reusable wizards like the ones that Salesforce uses in the Setup.

[image]

The logic of switching between steps and showing the current status should be encapsulated / managed by  and  components which allow to be given custom content in their body.

I am currently strugling with many issues:

1. Where should I manage the state over multiple steps? Apex, Js, Cache, ...?
2. How to make it work on `lightning:actionOverride` AND `force:lightningQuickAction` where the one is wrapped by a modal already?
3. How to have multiple screens in a modal? Or should I load another modal for each step?

...and thought myself maybe someone has build something similar and can share a few **ideas and or code**.

Comment: This https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9jGjkr-xm4&t=8s is a 1 hour presentation on building a wizard in a modal in Lightning.